# bind-address how does it work in mysql

Tags: mysql, configuration

I have a mysql running with bind-address "10.4.0.211".

From the documentation, I understand it like, the server accepts connections only from the IP - 10.4.0.211.

But I could able to connect to this mysql from another new server with the below configurations.

```
eth0      inet addr:10.8.0.7  
eth1      inet addr:10.11.0.50  
lo        inet addr:127.0.0.1
```

None of the above  has the bind address in them, but how come I am able to connect to the service. Please clarify.

I am suing the below connections string from the new server.

```
mysql -u<<username>> -p<<password>>  -h<<hostname of the mysql running server>> -A
```

Comment: I think you've got it backwards; mysql only accept connection **at** the bind-address, not **from**

Comment: as @towr mentioned, bind is where mysql is listening in on incoming connection, not the expected `from` address

Comment: @towr & nrathaus, thanks for your answer. I got it that i understood it reverse. now i have one more thing to ask... If with bind address, we cant control the external users or IP's, then what is it meant for ?

Comment: For example, you can use it to make mysql listen only to a local netwerk ip (or only localhost). That way people from outside the local network (or from another server) can't talk to it.